# Clear ASO region with dynamic members in Oracle Essbase

Tags: oracle, mdx, essbase

I have a problem in clearing a region in an Oracle ESSBASE ASO cube that returns in an error like:

> dynamic members are not allowed in data clear region specification

when i try to execute this query

> alter database 'aso'.'db' clear data in region
>   '{CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin({[var1]},{[var2]}),{[var3]}),{[var4]}),{[var5]}),{[a],[b],[c],[d]}),{Descendants([node],Levels([dim1],0))}),{Descendants([dim2],Levels([dim3],0))}),{Descendants([dim4],Levels([node1],0))}),{Descendants([dim5],Levels([node2],0))})}'
>   physical;

In my case there are level 0 dynamic members in dim5.

As you can see i tried the "physical" approach as found in some oracle forums but with without success.
I want to work at leaf level for each node, excluding the ones marked as dynamic.
How can I achieve this? How can I exclude from the query dynamic members in the hyerarchy and, as in my case, only dynamic leaf?

Help is very appreciated.

Thank you